Cubic equation conditions
The equation $ -4x^3+3x-v=0 $ has three solutions, according to WolframAlpha:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=-4x%5E3+%2B+0x%5E2+%2B3x+-v+%3D0
$$x = \frac{1}{2} \left((\sqrt{v^2 - 1} - v)^{1/3} + \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2 - 1} - v}\right)^{1/3}\right)$$
$$x = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}(\sqrt{v^2 - 1} - v)^{1/3} - \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2 - 1} - v}\right)^{1/3}\right)$$
$$x = \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}(\sqrt{v^2 - 1} - v)^{1/3} + \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{v^2 - 1} - v}\right)^{1/3}\right)$$
Leb be a $ \theta . $ We know the equation holds for $x=\sin\frac{\theta}{3}, v=\sin\theta .$ My question is, which of these three equations we have to choose so that $ \frac{\arcsin{v}}{3} =\arcsin x . $ It depends on $v$? $v$ is a real value between $ [-1,1]. $

The other solutions are $$x=\sin\frac{\theta\pm2\pi}3.$$ Why cannot you use those as solutions of the cubic?

Because if we choose $\theta=0^{\circ }$ , then none of the three work, exactly. How to tell a computer to show an exact expression of $ \sin(\theta /3) $ in terms of $ \sin (\theta) $ ?

Can you constrain $\theta$ to an interval? Otherwise you have the problem that $\theta$ and $\theta\pm2\pi$ give the same value for $\sin\theta$, but different values for $\sin(\theta/3)$.

$\theta\in (-90^{\circ} ,+90^{\circ}] . $ In my previous comment I made a mistake, sorry. The first of the general equations works, indeed, for $ \theta=0^{\circ} . $ However, if we change, say, $ \theta =45^{\circ} , $ then, the same equation doesn't hold. LHS would be $\sin 15^{\circ} , $ while RHS would be $ 1/\sqrt{2} $ . So, Cardano is useless?

At least for me Mathematica gives values in the range $[-1/2,1/2]$ using the bottom formula $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+i \sqrt{3}\right)
\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{-v+i \sqrt{1-v^2}}}+\frac{1}{2} \left(-1-i
\sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{-v+i \sqrt{1-v^2}}\right)$$
when $v$ is in the interval $[-1,1]$. Is that what you want?

Thank you for your info. What I didn't realize is that Cardano's cube root is multi-valued. What I'm doing is some research on the complex unit circle, to see whether I can describe complex root functions as single valued functions, bypassing the notion of radians. I hope that's possible. We'll see.
